# Tensorflow : How to build efficient NLP pipeline using tf Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am working on TensorFlow and trying to create an efficient training and inference pipeline using tf.dataset API but facing some error :

For example, a simple RNN network structure is like this :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# hyper parameters
vocab_size          = 20
word_embedding_dim  = 100
batch_size          = 2



tf.reset_default_graph()
# placeholders
sentences             = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None,None], name='sentences')
targets               = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='labels' )
keep_prob             = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1,], name='dropout')
keep_prob             = tf.cast(keep_prob.shape[0],tf.float32)


# embedding
word_embedding         = tf.get_variable(name='word_embedding_',
                                             shape=[vocab_size, word_embedding_dim],
                                             dtype=tf.float32,
                                             initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
embedding_lookup = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(word_embedding, sentences)



#  bilstm model
with tf.variable_scope('forward'):
    fr_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units = 15)
    dropout_fr = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(fr_cell, output_keep_prob = 1. - keep_prob)

with tf.variable_scope('backward'):
    bw_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units = 15)
    dropout_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(bw_cell, output_keep_prob = 1. - keep_prob)

with tf.variable_scope('bi-lstm') as scope:
    model,last_state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(dropout_fr,
                                                       dropout_bw,
                                                       inputs=embedding_lookup,
                                                       dtype=tf.float32)

logits             = tf.transpose(tf.concat(model, 2), [1, 0, 2])[-1]
linear_projection  = tf.layers.dense(logits, 5)



#loss
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = linear_projection, labels = tf.cast(targets,tf.float32))
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(cross_entropy, axis=1))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001).minimize(loss)
```

And dummy data is :

```
dummy_data    = [[1,3,4,5,5,12],[1,3,4,4,12,0],[12,4,12,0,0,0],[1,3,4,5,5,12]]
dummpy_labels = [[1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0]]
```

Now How I typically train this network by defining slice and pad sequences manually :

```
#  pad and slice 


def get_train_data(batch_size, slice_no):

    batch_data_j = np.array(dummy_data[slice_no * batch_size:(slice_no + 1) * batch_size])
    batch_labels = np.array(dummpy_labels[slice_no * batch_size:(slice_no + 1) * batch_size])

    max_sequence = max(list(map(len, batch_data_j)))

    # getting Max length of sequence
    padded_sequence = [i + [0] * (max_sequence - len(i)) if len(i) < max_sequence else i for i in batch_data_j]
    return padded_sequence, batch_labels




# dropout 0.2 during training and 0.0 during inference
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    iteration = len(dummy_data) // batch_size

    for iter_ in range(iteration):

        sentences_, labels_ = get_train_data(2,iter_)
        loss_,_ = sess.run([loss,optimizer], feed_dict= {sentences: sentences_, targets: labels_, keep_prob : 0.2})
        print(loss_)
```

Now want to use tf dataset pipeline to build an efficient pipeline for training and inference. I went through some tutorials but couldn't find good answer.

I tried to use tf.dataset like :

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((sentences,targets,keep_prob))
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types)
iterator_initializer_ = iterator.make_initializer(dataset, name='initializer')
sentec, labels, drop_  = iterator.get_next()



def initialize_iterator(sess, sentences_, labels_, drops_):

        feed_dict = {sentences: sentences_, targets: labels_, keep_prob : [np.random.randint(0,2,[1,]).astype(np.float32)]}

        return sess.run(iterator_initializer_, feed_dict = feed_dict)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    iteration = len(dummy_data) // batch_size

    for iter_ in range(iteration):
        initialize_iterator(sess, dummy_data, dummpy_labels, [0.0])
        los, _ = sess.run([loss, optimizer])
        print(los)
```

But I am getting an error.

So what should be an efficient pipeline for training RNN and encoding, padding with dropout sequences using dataset api?

Comment: What does _getting an error_ mean? Why are there seemingly two questions in here; do you want to make your code more efficient (whatever that means), or fix the bug?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I know the old way to feed the dict, I am looking for an efficient way to train that model using tf.dataset api.

Comment: Pardon? I’m not sure what that has to do with my comment.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile what I meant, I just don't want to correct that error, I am looking for an efficient way to use tf.dataset API for training that network, I was using old method which I have shown in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you preparing your data into some other formats: for example, `CSV` or `TFRecord`. Then you could use `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` or `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` to read the data into tf.data object directly.

There are tutorials on this topic [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#reading_input_data).

If you are using `TFRecord`, one example (in [`tensorflow.Example` proto buffer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto#L88) text format) would look like this:

```
features {
  feature {
    key: "sentences"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: "0"
        value: "55"
        value: "128"
      }
    }
  }
  feature {
    key: "targets"
    value {
      int64_list {
        value: "10001"
        value: "10002"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would use `keep_prob` and `batch_size` as model configuration parameters. You don't need to embed them in the examples.

Once you have your training and evaluation examples [created](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord) in `TFRecord` format above and serialized, it would be straightforward to build your data pipeline.

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames = [your_tf_record_file])
```

Based on the dataset, you could build your `input_fn`, then you could continue with either `tf.Estimator` api or Keras API. One example tutorial is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/keras_model_to_estimator#create_an_input_function).